# QMake Linking Problem With GCC

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, makefile, qmake

I have a problem with qmake and the make file that it generates. My program needs to be linked against two libraries. I add them in main.pro as follows.

```
LIBS += -L lib/somelib1/bin -lsomelib1 -L lib/somelib2/bin -lsomelib2
```

How ever I arrange the above line qmake tells gcc this.

```
g++ -o programname someobject.o -L lib/somelib1/bin lib/somelib2/bin -lsomelib1 -lsomelib2
```

The problem is that it should look like this.

```
g++ -o programname someobject.o -L lib/somelib1/bin -L lib/somelib2/bin -lsomelib1
-lsomelib2
```

GCC gives the following error.

```
lib/somelib2/bin: file not recognized: Is a directory
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put spaces between the flags and the arguments:

```
LIBS += -Llib/somelib1/bin -lsomelib1 -Llib/somelib2/bin -lsomelib2
```

Or

```
LIBS += -L"lib/somelib1/bin" -lsomelib1 -L"lib/somelib2/bin" -lsomelib2
```

And why are your static/import libraries in the "bin" directory? There should be `.a` files in the "lib" directory.

Comment: Cheers that worked. I had spaces with just one library and that worked so I assumed the same will hold for another. Not sure what you meant by static/import comment.

Comment: The "usual"/"canonical" way to build/install libraries is to place static or import libraries (and Linux `.so`s) in `someprefix/lib`, and any executable files or in case of Windows DLL's, in `someprefix/bin`. You'd pass to the linker the first directory, and add to PATH the second directory. I just fear you're linking directly to the DLL (which works fine, but is not portable in the sense mentioned above; on Linux, it will break, because the libraries you'd normally link to are in a different directory). Just nitpicking here, if it works, don't fix it!

Comment: Cheers but these are static libraries that are getting built with the project. I have imported these libraries (whick I have made) using git submodules. These libraries are also qt and get compiled into the executable.

Comment: For the curious: The reason why the OP's line did not work is that a variable in Qt is simply a list of items.  The "-L xxxx -L yyyy" got stuffed into the list as {-L, xxxx, -L, yyyy}.  When it came time to put the link line together, the LIBS was "cleaned up" and duplicates removed ({-L, xxxx, yyyy}).

Answer (score -1):

You could try putting the library search paths under the QMAKE_LIBDIR tag. So your qmake file would have:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += lib/somelib1/bin lib/somelib2/bin
LIBS += -lsomelib1 -lsomelib2
```